# What is the probability of ice in boiling water?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, entropy, states-of-matter, poincare-recurrence

Ice crystals are spatially ordered, and in every randomness there is a low possibility of temporarily order. If given enough boiling water, and sufficient time, could local clusters water molecules happen to be in a crystalized state?

This may seem absurd, but I believe it must be possible, imagine dropping an ice cube in boiling water(and water vapor) in a perfect closed system, the ice cube melts while the water keeps boiling (because of the water vapor), then because of Poincare recurrence theorem, there  will be an similar ice cube after a sufficiently long but finite time.

EDIT: The temperature is 100 Celsius and 1 atm (not at triple point)

Comment: Do not hold your breath. It is the same answer  to "what is the probability that all the air ends up in the upper right corner of the room and we suffocate".

Comment: So is there a small chance it might snow in the upper right hand corner of the room?

Comment: @Jitter, no it'll snow in the lower left corner, so we'll die w/o even getting a single run down the slope :-)

Comment: At the triple point of water, the probability is quite high.

Comment: @OlinLathrop true, but I don't think you can convince water to boil at the triple point.

Comment: You can, just decrease the pressure below 611 Pa.

Comment: @Carl: At the triple point is right on the edge between all three phases of water.  Any liquid will boil with just little extra heat or lower pressure, or will freeze with just a little less heat.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann%27s_entropy_formula) in the wiki

> In statistical mechanics, Boltzmann's equation is a probability equation relating the entropy S of an ideal gas to the quantity W, which is the number of microstates corresponding to a given macrostate :

[image: Boltzman formula]

In this formula connecting the statistical  probability to entropy arising from thermodynamics  one sees that *all* microstates are counted in. This would include the subset of microstates that  are postuled in the question.

To get a probability number, one would have to do all the permutations of molecules at that temperature and pressure to appear in the volume under consideration and take the ratio to all the possible configurations with the rest of the molecules. In normal temperatures and pressures this would be a very very very  small number for boiling water, and I am not willing to do the calculations for it. In addition  one would have to include the phase transition into the calculations also ( or the binding  of water molecules in the two forms).

In a supersaturated vapor, [as in a cloud chamber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_chamber) or up high in the atmosphere where the jets leave track, the probability is quite high once a seed appears that the phase transition will happen, but that is another story.