# What is the probability that all the air ends up in the upper right corner of the room and we suffocate

Tags: statistical-mechanics, probability

Since someone commented this on this question([What is the probability of ice in boiling water?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/93345/what-is-the-probability-of-ice-in-boiling-water?noredirect=1#comment190832_93345)), I would like to ask what is the probability that all the air ends up in the upper right corner of the room and we suffocate, considering that brain death happens after 10 minutes, and an average room has 40 cubic meters of air.

Comment: I must have read this "corner of the room" somewhere since it came up in  a google search here  http://www.upscale.utoronto.ca/GeneralInterest/Harrison/Entropy/Entropy.html paragraph : "the entropy of a closed system never increases" . The probability will be very very very small, equal to 0 as far as numbers go, and not worth calculating. See answers to this question http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070103164834AAIZB65

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/542/chance-of-objects-going-against-greater-entropy/ and physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20401/is-a-world-with-constant-decreasing-entropy-theoretically-impossible . The probability is very small, it's like  saying you can go through the wall by tunnel effect. You could try to run a simulation with, say 1000 particles and see what is the probability.